# How to validate the SignedXML for the following code?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am working on one project where I need to check if the `XML` provided is valid or not.
For this purpose, I am using code to verify the `XML` using the `signedXml`class in  c#.

Please find the below code for the `verify()` Method:

```
    public bool Verify(XmlDocument signedDocument)
{
    // create a signed xml object from xml 
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(signedDocument);
    // get the signature node and load the signature tag
    XmlNodeList nodeList = signedDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

    // define and create the encryption key
    CspParameters CSPParam = new CspParameters();
    CSPParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(CSPParam);
    rsa.FromXmlString(@"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>03COUbx8JI6jkkmxrQ3N//67tgMt+ak1SKSXbGO3+4vVGFGhyGICJS8C+W6ON6dUdcm2/uxC5q4wyPRyFWMf8v8oslGOWJdADPnP8rvcy8PL3Nf67f8fMnTyHoEoZTfZjKuEoyhmPi6rfAX4QQA+OYhk4Qb1FJyOB3fpZ1QiTxX2k=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");

    // load encryption key to the xml
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue(rsa));
    signedXml.KeyInfo=keyInfo;
    // check if the signature provided in signature tag is valid with the key info
    bool b = signedXml.CheckSignature();
    return b;
}
```

and the xml data provided to the method is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" id="MySignature">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#_ea559faf-417b-407f-bdc2-bccc76dab76c">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
          </Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>fvQx+J90ZGKhwj8Mfhg6v/esOtI=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>fvQx+J90ZGKhwj8Mfhg6v/esOtI=</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#RSAKeyValue">    
   <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>03COUbx8JI6jkLrQ3N//67tgMt+ak1SKSXbGO3+4vVGFGhyGICJS8C+W6ON6dUdcm2/uxC5q4wyPRyFWMf8v8oslGOWJdADPnP8rvcy8PL3Nf67f8fMnTyHoEoZTfZjKuEoyhmPi6rfAX4QQA+OYhk4Qb1FJyOB3fpZ1QiTxX2k=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
  </KeyInfo >   
</Signature>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am not able to trace out which tag value in `xml` I am setting wrong.
The result of `signedXml.CheckSignature()` is always getting `false`.

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem?

Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the errors.  From menu in VS  : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Then paste you xml into page making sure there is only one xml id line starting in column one.  The look for warnings or errors.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="MySignature">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#_ea559faf-417b-407f-bdc2-bccc76dab76c">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
          </Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>fvQx+J90ZGKhwj8Mfhg6v/esOtI=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>fvQx+J90ZGKhwj8Mfhg6v/esOtI=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns:type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#RSAKeyValue">
      <KeyValue>
        <RSAKeyValue>
           <Modulus>03COUbx8JI6jkLrQ3N//67tgMt+ak1SKSXbGO3+4vVGFGhyGICJS8C+W6ON6dUdcm2/uxC5q4wyPRyFWMf8v8oslGOWJdADPnP8rvcy8PL3Nf67f8fMnTyHoEoZTfZjKuEoyhmPi6rfAX4QQA+OYhk4Qb1FJyOB3fpZ1QiTxX2k=</Modulus>
           <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        </RSAKeyValue>
      </KeyValue>
    </KeyInfo >
  </Signature>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You needed xmlns:type and were missing KeyValue tag

Comment: You should also have a capital "I" instead of a lower case "i" : Id="MySignature"

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer.
But, Still the `bool b = signedXml.CheckSignature();` is giving me output as false.
I am looking for some changes which will give me the above code statement value as `true`

Comment: I used wewbpage below to decrypted message using your modulus, key, and encrypted message and got the value 1.  You may be getting the text which includes a percentage sign.  See following webpage : https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa11/notes/10.1_Cryptography/RSA_Express_EncryptDecrypt.html

Comment: I cant get it. Can you please elaborate at some extend.

Comment: I have tried for the decryption of RSA Modulus tag but not able to get the key for that.